# Error calling a javascript function via modules.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I return a function to modules.export like this in a file testmessage.js

```
module.exports = function () {
  console.log("TestMessage");
};
```

and reference it like this in an other file:

```
var testmessage = require('./testmessage');
```

the call of the function

```
testmessage();
```

results in the attached error message:

```
> /home/mi01/Projekte/app.js:3 testmessage(); 
> testmessage();
> ^
> 
> TypeError: testmessage is not a function
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mi01/Projekte/app.js:3:1)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
>     at startup (node.js:140:18)
>     at node.js:1001:3
```

I am useing node.js version v5.6.0 on Ubuntu 15.10.  Technically this seems ok for me, why is the error thrown?

Comment: It works fine in my copy of v5.4.1

Comment: It works fine for me. You have more code you are not showing. Please try this for app.js: `var testmessage = require('./testmessage');
testmessage();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not see any issue I have reinstalled node.js via 'apt-get install nodejs --reinstall' and the unchanged code runs! The node.js version did not change!!